# Can anyone explain how this recursion code works exactly and what happens in the programs stack or in memory step by step?

Tags: c, recursion

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void fun(int n)
{
    if(n > 0)
    {
        fun(n-1);
        printf("%d ", n);
        fun(n-1);
    }
}

int main()
{
    fun(4);
    return 0;
}
```

and the output of this code is `1 2 1 3 1 2 1 4 1 2 1 3 1 2 1`.
But I can't understand what happens exactly between to recursive calls, When the print statement will be executed and what is the value of `n` at every call.
I'm beginner in coding please explain step by step.

Comment: It's a high time you learn to use a debugger to step through the code.

Comment: I would recommend looking up how to use a debugger.  It will allow you to step through the code as it is running and show you the local variables in each step.

Comment: Try it with pencil and paper. Note: there is nothing "between" recursive calls.

Comment: If you can't use a debugger, add this at the top of `fun`: `printf("Entering call to fun with n == %d\n", n);` Then realise that, before the first `printf("%d ", n);` call is made, you've already called `fun` 4 times

Comment: Think of a binary tree... that might help.

Comment: If you can't use a debugger, you need to learn how before you write even one more line of code, else you will be continually posting questions to SO:(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will be much easier to understand what is happening if you start with what happens closer to the base case of the recursion. Suppose you have `fun(0)` in your `main`. inside the body of `fun` this happens:

```
void fun(int n)
{
    if(n > 0) //this is false, so function does nothing
    {
        fun(n-1);
        printf("%d ", n);
        fun(n-1);
    }
}
```

now what if you have `foo(1)` in your `main` ?

```
void fun(int n)
{
    if(n > 0) //this is true, lets execute the block
    {
        fun(n-1); //call fun(0), this does nothing
        printf("%d ", n); //print value 1
        fun(n-1);//call fun(0) again, does nothing
    }
}
```

so you can see that `fun(1)` will print value 1, how about `fun(2)`?

```
void fun(int n)
{
    if(n > 0) 
    {
        fun(n-1);        //call fun(1), prints 1
        printf("%d ", n);//print value 2
        fun(n-1);        //call fun(1), prints 1
    }
}
```

so as you can see `foo(2)` will print "1 2 1", similarly `foo(3)` will print 1 2 1 3 1 2 1

how the stack builds up and unwinds is very interesting and you should sit down with pen and paper and figure that out.

This is called pure structural recursion, you get closer to base case every step of the recursion.